# Definition of electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

[In wikipedia about electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field), it define electrostaatic field as electric fields that do not change with time.

[And article about electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential), it define electrostatic field is a vector quantity expressed as the gradient of the electrostatic potential, which is a scalar quantity denoted by $V$.

But i'm not convinced about they mean same thing, exactly.
$\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ means that electric field dosen't change with time?

Or there is good definition of electrostatic field?

Comment: The term electrostatics typically means there are no moving charges, so the electric field from stationary charges won't change with time. The gradient operator takes partial derivatives with respect to spatial coordinates (and multiplies the respective partial derivatives with unit vectors to give vector output). So no, there is no time dependency in the electrostatic potential or electrostatic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that an electrostatic field is a field E(r) that does not depend on time. You seem to be confused by the definition

$$ -\nabla \phi(r) = E(r)$$

Maybe it would help to contrast this with the time dependent version

$$-\nabla \phi - \frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{t}}$$
where A is the magnetic vector potential. In other words you can have a nice definition of the electrostatic field as the field arising from purely the gradient of a scalar potential. If the potential has a time dependence then you will have non trivial A that will give you time varying fields.